# SQL Server - Difference between NOT IN and != ANY + subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

My main goal is to get the IDs of companies who had a payment during the 01/01/2018 to 31/01/2018 (D1) but nothing since 01/02/2018 to 31/01/2018 (D2) (the churn).

I solved it by getting all the IDs in D1 and exclude every IDs I got in D2 like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       p.id_association
FROM dbo.paiement p
WHERE p.statut = 'OK'
      AND p.date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-01-31'
      AND p.id_association != ANY
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
           p2.id_association
    FROM dbo.paiement p2
    WHERE p2.statut = 'OK'
          AND p2.date BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND '2019-01-31'
);
```

But the result is WAY much higher than excepted. So I asked the guy in charge before and he told me using **NOT IN** instead of my **!= ANY** which gives my a 100x lower result more close than what there are excepted (normal if the previous query was wrong for many years).

So what happen behind `!= ANY (subQ)` VS `NOT IN (subQ)` ?

Which one is the good one and why ?

EDIT : `!= ALL` do the job but I prefer the `NOT EXISTS` version.

Comment: Insert some null values in the id_association columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly recommend `not exists` in this case:

```
not exists (select 1
            from dbo.paiement p2
            where p2.id_association = p.id_association and
                  p2.statut = 'AUTHORIZED' and
                  p2.date between '2018-02-01' and '2019-01-31'
           )
```

`NOT IN` returns *no rows at all* if the subquery returns *any* `NULL` values.

If you use `<>` then you want `<> ALL`, not `<> ANY`.  The latter is basically true when there are two ids in the subquery (and other cases as well).

Comment: Thank you for your recommandation. NOT IN and NOT EXISTS returns me the same result. In this case it's impossible to have null values here but NOT EXISTS seems to be faster.

My first guess is wrong after comparing some data. But I would to know why this is not what I was expected ?

Comment: @Ragnar . . . The last paragraph explains why `<> ANY` does't do what you want.

Comment: Did you edit your comment because I didn't see it at first. Never mind I figured it out by myself. Thanks !